# how to start adf application in Djbo.debugoutput=console mode

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I need to start my adf application with  "-Djbo.debugoutput=console."

How can i do it?
I am using jdevloper 11.1.1.6

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is add the above string as a Java Option into the Run/Debug configuration.

[image]
[image]

[image]